# Rooted phone having problems with switching on

Tags: rooting, screen, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I recently rooted my samsung galaxy s5, i did something wrong on one of custom roms, I thought I was installing the new system or something, it got me into the boot system.
I choose apply (something) and it restarted... ever since I cannot switch my phone.
I mean it does switch on but then the home screen is completely black, and the notification shows `unfortunately, settings has stopped` it shows a notification to almost every single app saying it stop working. Once I press OK every single notification, it just black screen, nothing changes if I press anything.
I tried to restarting, rebooting, re-rooting...nothing.
Does anyone have a solution for this.

Comment: What about Factory reset? You can go to recovery I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest going back to official firmware. its the only thing i can think of. if you want to download official firmware got to this page http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/ and find your variant, its latest firmware, and install it. the page has instructions as well.